# Moving Wordpress from Apache to IIS

Tags: apache, iis, wordpress, .htaccess

I've encountered a problem when moving a Wordpress installation from a Linux Apache server to a Windows IIS server. Nearly all pages load blank, including /wp-admin/. I created a php file in the main directory to check phpinfo, and it loads fine.

I've copied the file system over, as well as the database. I've also updated the wp-config.php with the correct credentials.

I think it has something to do with .htaccess, but I'm not sure how to correct it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.htaccess is not used on Windows IIS servers.

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/557/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig/

Comment: You can also directly import your .htaccess file as URL Rewrite rules in IIS using IIS Manager.

Comment: Yes, however how does Wordpress normally operate on IIS then? Or doesn't it?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you have a permalink problem, compounded by the fact that permalinks operate differently on IIS than Linux. See: [Using Permalinks « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Permalinks_without_mod_rewrite)

Try resetting permalinks to default in Dashbord/Settings/Permalinks, if you can get into Admin. If not, you need to go into the database with phpmyadminand manually clear the permalink field in wp_options, usually around option 34.

**Update:** And, did you change domains? Or just hosting? See this, too: [Moving WordPress « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)

Comment: Changed both Domains and Hosting, I'm going to try this and report back if I have any success

Comment: It didn't fix it, however it seems to be something in the database it doesn't like. I tried pointing the filesystem to a different database, with freshly installed data, and it worked without any problems.