# Should I avoid installing WordPress in IIS?

Tags: iis, wordpress

I was asked to install numerous WordPress sites in IIS. I'm wondering, should try to convince my clients to use Apache instead? Should I avoid using IIS?

Things I'm concerned about:
1 - According to this Q&A, permalinks work differently in IIS : [Moving Wordpress from Apache to IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993221/moving-wordpress-from-apache-to-iis)

2 - I have to find IIS specific instructions for fixing problems that may not have occurred if I used Apache. Which can get very annoying.

3 - The latest version of WordPress may not work as expected in IIS.

4 - Insert some other problem I might come across using ISS instead of Apache

Am I right in trying to avoid IIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are all sorts of reasons based in technical details of the differences in LAMP and IIS, but simply tell them that performance and security is much better under Apache. From their perspective, that will save time and money, and usually those are the most important things to clients.

Comment: I fundamentally agree with this statement, but I've found that clients with only Windows experience get a little spooked by moving outside their comfort zone. Since the OP mentions multiple IIS sites, I'm guessing this is a dedicated host running Windows ???. If this is moved to a LAMP environment, who is their sysadmin? I've been mainly doing Django sites on dedicated servers for the last couple of years but am now seriously looking at WP 3.0 on shared hosting for smaller clients because of the overall cost of ownership issues.

Comment: @Peter - Yes, this is a dedicated host running Windows.  you have a good point, the move to LAMP may depend on the Sysadmin. They are a Microsoft shop.

@songdogtech - You have a good point as well.  I would need to give the clients some hard facts... or at the very least, some URLs.  I'll start researching that soon. 

My fear is that the sysadmin might end up being me.  And I only have experience with apache.  I'm simply wondering how much I need to push the issue of IIS vs Apache to the client.